# How to compile 32bit x86 application in x86_64-w64-mingw32 gcc-8.1.0 with my *.lds file in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw32, lds

I have some **attribute**((used, section ... )) codes, so I need modify the main.lds file.

1. run ld --verbose >> main.lds to generate the default main.lds file. It's 64 bits version, I need 32 bits version.
2. modify main.lds

   OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
   .bss BLOCK(**section_alignment**) :
   {
   *(.app_init.0)
   *(.app_init.1)
   *(.app_init.2) ....
3. modify tasks.json file in vscode.

   ```
      "command": "gcc.exe",
      "args": [                         
          "-g",
          "-m32",
          "-fshort-enums",      
          "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c", 
          "'-Wl,-Tmain.lds'",         
          "'-Wl,-Map=${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\${workspaceRootFolderName}.map'",                                                                                                                        
          "-o", "${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\${workspaceRootFolderName}.exe",                
         ],
   ```
4. then I get 32bits main.exe, but it cannot run:
   Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0xffffffff in ?? ()

Did I miss something in the main.lds file?

( 1. if I don't modify main.lds and delete "-m32" in tasks.json, I can get 64bit main.exe and it run correctly. and my sections code also run correctly.
2. if I delete "'-Wl,-Tmain.lds'" in tasks.json, I can get 32bit main.exe with default lds file and it run correctly. but my sections code don't run correctly. )

need help. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this problem.
gcc -m32 main.c  '-Wl,--verbose'  can output 32 bits version lds file contents.
this lds file is correct!

Comment: The code/command part of the answer has to be inside the code quotes.